# Return Rows with Unique and Duplicate values from dataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have 5 rows in a Datatable.There is a column named,say "duplicate". Based on that column, i want all those rows which want distinct values in column "duplicate".
And also i want rows which have been rejected.

```
var duplicateRecords = (from rows in outputTable.AsEnumerable()  select rows.Field<string>("duplicate") into grp
where grp.Count() > 1
select grp).Distinct();
```

The above written code return the values in Column "duplicate". However i want the whole row.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
var duplicateRecords = outputTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("duplicate"))
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() == 1)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp)
    .Distinct();
```

This should return only duplicate rows (Not in front of VS so there might be some typos).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Its not returning the desired result. its showing only those rows which have  duplicate records in "Duplicate" column. Its not returning the unique rows.

Comment: So you want the unique rows? From your question it seems you were looking to get one copy of each duplicate row